# 'pyapi.eval_loader' undefined in: pyapi.eval_loader(0x7f34f01f2c60:ptr, "{_emit.emit( { 'event_date': '2019-10-10', 'status': 1})};":str);

Tags: python-3.x, monetdb

**While trying to use Monet/Python Loader function,we are getting the following error**
    **pymonetdb.exceptions.OperationalError: 'pyapi.eval_loader' undefined in:     pyapi.eval_loader(0x7f34f01f2c60:ptr, "{_emit.emit( { 'event_date': '2019-10-10', 'status': 1})};":str);**

Followed the below steps for installation

**Python installation steps:**

```
We have installed python 3.6
1)yum install autoconf
2)yum install automake
3)yum install libtool
4)yum install openssl
5)yum install openssl-devel
6)yum install python-devel
7)Configured environment path settings for python   
    export PYTHONPATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

**Monet installation steps:**
    1)git clone https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB.git
    2)cd /MonetDB
    3)./bootstrap
    4)cd..
    5)mkdir testdir
    6)cd testdir
    7)../MonetDB/configure --enable-pyintegration=yes

While configuring we get the following status enabled message as below

*py3integration is enabled*

```
8)make
9)make install
10)monetdbd create /path/to/mydbfarm
11)monetdbd start /path/to/mydbfarm
12)monet stop -a
13)monet set embedpy=true
14)monet start -a
13)Enabled numpy(*pip install numpy*)
```

**Created a loader by using the below python script**

```
import pymonetdb
import sys
import os
connection = pymonetdb.connect(username="admin", password="admin@123", hostname="ipaddress", database="test")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE LOADER myloader() LANGUAGE PYTHON {_emit.emit( { 'event_date': '2019-10-10', 'status': 1})};") #create loader
cursor.execute("COPY LOADER INTO store FROM myloader();")  #append the row from loader to table
connection.commit()
```

*While running the above script getting the following error*

```
pymonetdb.exceptions.OperationalError: 'pyapi.eval_loader' undefined in:     pyapi.eval_loader(0x7f34f01f2c60:ptr, "{_emit.emit( { 'event_date': '2019-10-10', 'status': 1})};":str);
```

Please, help us to fix this issue.

Comment: People downvoting this question, what's wrong with you? It's a perfectly valid question, and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that you are mixing python 2 and 3.

```
yum install python3-devel python3-numpy
--enable-py3integration=yes
monetdb set embedpy3=true <database name>
```

Mind the `3`.
Also mind `monetdb` vs `monet`. 
And also that `monetdb set ...` needs a database name. You are setting parameters per database, not globally.